# I need to hide the "log out" option

Tags: flutter, authentication, visibility

Im new in flutter and i need some help to hide the "logout" option from my sidebar when the user is using the app without registering i already try to use the "visibility" widget but im not pretty sure how to make it works

Comment: Hi There. Use can just use a conditional like `loggedin ? logoutwidget() : null`. This `logoutwidget` will be your logout option.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably turn it into a widget and add a condition to it. For example, if you are logged in, you can return the widget that would display the logout button and if you are not logged in, you can just return null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FutureBuilder` for logout button as following

```
FutureBuilder<UserModel?>(
  future: userService.getUser(), // which returns a Future
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<UserModel?> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Button();
    }
    return Wrap();
),
```